# domain 'ubuntu-hvm' does not exists, xen + ubuntu, hvm guest os installation problem

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xen

I am following the installation/setup instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XenProposed to install ubuntu + xen. I was able to install a PV guest OS. However, when I got to the HVM guest OS part, I keep getting the statement:

```
error: domain 'ubuntu-hvm' does not exist
```

This error shows when I execute the following command:

```
sudo xm create /etc/xen/ubuntu-hvm.cfg
```

My `ubuntu-hvm.cfg` looks like the following:

```
builder = "hvm"
name = "ubuntu-hvm"
memory = "512"
vcpus = 1
vif = ['']
disk = ['phy:/dev/xenvg/ubuntu-hvm,hda,w','file:/home/jwayne/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso,hdc:cdrom,r']
vnc = 1
boot="dc"
```

I did some internet searches, and some site the `dhcp = 'dhcp'` line in the configuration file as the problem (which I do not have). I've also seen some variations of the configuration file where they set:

```
kernel = "/usr/lib/xen-4.1/boot/hvmloader"
```

which doesn't resolve the error message for me.

The way I create a logical volume is as follows:

```
sudo lvcreate -L 4G -n ubuntu-hvm /dev/xenvg
```

The logs at /var/log/xen/qemu-dm-ubuntu-hvm.log looks like the following.

```
Using file /dev/xenvg/ubuntu-hvm in read-write mode
Using file /home/jwayne/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso in read-only mode
Watching /local/domain/0/device-model/3/lodirty/cmd
Watching /local/domain/0/device-model/3/command
Watching /local/domain/3/cpu
qemu_map_cache_init nr_buckets = 10000 size 4194304
shared page at pfn feffd
buffered io page at pfn feffb
Guest uuid = d56fc9dd-0a2e-a797-8ebe-c4f0d7a4fae8
Time offset set 0
populating video RAM at ff000000
mapping video RAM at ff000000
Register xen platform.
Done register platform.
platform_fixed_ioport: changed ro/rw state of ROM memory area. now is rw state.
xs_read(/local/domain/0/device-model/3/xen_extended_power_mgmt): read error
Could not read keymap file: '/usr/share/qemu/keymaps/en-us'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Take a look at your /var/log/xen/qemu-dm-* log. That message happens when QEMU doesn't start correctly for some reason.

Comment: thanks, it seems the directory, /usr/share/qemu, doesn't even exists. however, there is a directory, /usr/share/qemu-linaro. i simply copied the directory: cp -fr /usr/share/qemu-linaro /usr/share/qemu. now the VM starts. thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @ToddDeshane though the HVM guest OS is running now, i can't seem to connect to it via VNC (using VNC Viewer from a Windows box). Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

When I had this problem with the same example it was because the keymap files were not in the correct directory.  The logs at `/var/log/xen/qemu-dm-ubuntu-hvm1.log` showed:

```
Could not read keymap file: '/usr/share/qemu/keymaps/en-us'
```

The quick solution was to make a symlink for, where the keymaps are now to where xen expects it:

```
ln -s /usr/share/qemu-linaro/ /usr/share/qemu/
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the qemu keymap issue can be worked around in the code by adding to the qemu search path with `-L <dir>`. I think [this github code change](https://github.com/djs55/xenopsd/commit/11845430505cc2658de87fab64d2775bd3429464) fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this link `ln -s /usr/share/qemu-linaro/ /usr/share/qemu/`, but without `/`

correct: `ln -s /usr/share/qemu-linaro /usr/share/qemu`

After that HVM started successfully